# Can't start Rails4 server when rails is installed under a user directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that     /home/joey/joeyhu.info/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
Exiting
    /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `initialize':     Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/joey/joeyhu.info/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `open'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `write_pid'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/joey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am getting an error when try to start rails server. I have a Ubuntu 13.10 on DigitalOcean and installed Rails and Ruby as a user(not with sudo). When I install rails with sudo, I didn't have this issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear

```
Unable to access log file. Please ensure that sure /home/joey/joeyhu.info/log/development.log exists
```

Make the directory accessible using chmod on all folders and files.